# Add filter and pagination to CAML query

Tags: 2010, development, caml-query, visual-web-part, caml

I'm developing a visual web part for Sharepoint 2010.

I would display all documents from a specific DL, but this DL contains more than 7000 items.

So I would like to add a pagination (show only 20 results per page) and display, above the list of files, some textbox and dropdown to filter the right content from the CAML query.

Which way do you suggest to do these two things?

Comment: How do you wish to work, Client/Server side? I d suggest u JTable or DataTables (jquery plugin)

Comment: I was thinking to a server side solution.

Answer (score 0):

For pagination, I recommend you reading this article (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbadki/archive/2008/10/08/caml-query-execution-using-pagination-for-custom-columns.aspx).

In your dropdownlist, load all the possible page numbers. And on every click, you relaunch the query and you got your paged result.